# Where do I place the intent code?

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, android-intent

Following are the .java files I had written to login to the app using mysql. I had found help on http://easyway2in.blogspot.in/2015/07/android-mysql-database-connect.html

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.soumya.attendance;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
public class MainActivity extends Activity{
    EditText ET_NAME,ET_PASS;
    String login_name,login_pass;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ET_NAME = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        ET_PASS = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    }
    public void userLogin(View view)
    {
        login_name = ET_NAME.getText().toString();
        login_pass = ET_PASS.getText().toString();
        String method = "login";
        BackgroundTask backgroundTask = new BackgroundTask(this);
        backgroundTask.execute(method,login_name,login_pass);
    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        return;
    }
}
```

BackgroundActivity.java

```
    package com.example.soumya.attendance;
        import android.app.AlertDialog;
        import android.content.Context;
        import android.content.Intent;
        import android.os.AsyncTask;
        import android.widget.Toast;
        import java.io.BufferedReader;
        import java.io.BufferedWriter;
        import java.io.IOException;
        import java.io.InputStream;
        import java.io.InputStreamReader;
        import java.io.OutputStream;
        import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
        import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
        import java.net.MalformedURLException;
        import java.net.URL;
        import java.net.URLEncoder;
public class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {
    AlertDialog alertDialog;
    Context ctx;
    BackgroundTask(Context ctx)
    {
        this.ctx =ctx;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("Login Information....");
    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String reg_url = "http://10.0.2.2/webapp/register.php";
        String login_url = "http://10.0.2.2/login.php";
        String method = params[0];
        if (method.equals("register")) {
            String name = params[1];
            String user_name = params[2];
            String user_pass = params[3];
            try {
                URL url = new URL(reg_url);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                //httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                OutputStream OS = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(OS, "UTF-8"));
                String data = URLEncoder.encode("user", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(name, "UTF-8") + "&" +
                        URLEncoder.encode("user_name", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(user_name, "UTF-8") + "&" +
                        URLEncoder.encode("user_pass", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(user_pass, "UTF-8");
                bufferedWriter.write(data);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                OS.close();
                InputStream IS = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                IS.close();
                //httpURLConnection.connect();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                return "Registration Success...";
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else if(method.equals("login"))
        {
            String login_name = params[1];
            String login_pass = params[2];
            try {
                URL url = new URL(login_url);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream,"UTF-8"));
                String data = URLEncoder.encode("login_name","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(login_name,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                        URLEncoder.encode("login_pass","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(login_pass,"UTF-8");
                bufferedWriter.write(data);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                outputStream.close();
                InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"iso-8859-1"));
                String response = "";
                String line = "";
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!=null)
                {
                    response+= line;
                }
                bufferedReader.close();
                inputStream.close();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                return response;
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        if(result.equals("Registration Success..."))
        {
            Toast.makeText(ctx, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else
        {
            alertDialog.setMessage(result);
            alertDialog.show();
            }
        }
    }
```

Now, I want to add an intent code so that if the user logs in successfully, he/she will be taken to the other activity. But, if I try to place it in MainActivity.java, it does not check for successful login or not. Please help me with it. Many others also have the same question on the source. Here, my login.php returns a result to notify whether the login is successful or not through echo.

Comment: inside the onPostExecute

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its Simple,

Just place on the Intent code on Post Execute when the login Success

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        if(result.equals("Registration Success..."))
        {
            Toast.makeText(ctx, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        //Place the Intent Code Here.

        Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");
        intent.setClassName("com.your.package","com.your.package.MainActivity");
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);

        }
        else
        {
            alertDialog.setMessage(result);
            alertDialog.show();
            }
        }
```

Happy Coding :)

Comment: Intent code cannot be placed there because BackgroundActivity class does not extend Activity. So, startActivity shows an error. And we cannot add extends Activity to BackgroundActivity class because it already extends Async.

Comment: try the Updated Answer

Comment: Run the background Task in MainActivityClass (or) use StartActivityForResult.( http://www.javatpoint.com/android-startactivityforresult-example )

Comment: Intent for BackgroundActivity itself does not work. I tried the possibility of running background task in MainActivity.java, but it shows a null pointer exception saying the result returned by login.php is becoming null. Please help me out by suggesting a neater code for my implementation

Comment: Complete Tutorial for Android Login and Registration with PHP, MySQL and SQLite (  http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/  )

Comment: I am sorry...we tried all of these possibilities. Didn't find any help. That is the reason I wanted a personal help. Thanks

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't check your updated answer. I tried placing it in my code. But for some reason it shows an error at startActivity(intent); Do I have to import anything for it?